# How Would I Make an External Database File? - Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, discord.js

I am trying to build a discord bot, that would do leveling and warns and such, but i have no idea how I would link a file to the main javascript file so i can have all the database code be "external". I want to use SQLite for my database.

This is currently what i have

```js
client.on("ready", () => {
  // Check if the table "points" exists.
  const table = sql.prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name = 'scores';").get();
  if (!table['count(*)']) {
    // If the table isn't there, create it and setup the database correctly.
    sql.prepare("CREATE TABLE scores (id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, user TEXT, guild TEXT, points INTEGER, level INTEGER);").run();
    // Ensure that the "id" row is always unique and indexed.
    sql.prepare("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_scores_id ON scores (id);").run();
    sql.pragma("synchronous = 1");
    sql.pragma("journal_mode = wal");
  }

  // And then we have two prepared statements to get and set the score data.
  client.getScore = sql.prepare("SELECT * FROM scores WHERE user = ? AND guild = ?");
  client.setScore = sql.prepare("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO scores (id, user, guild, points, level) VALUES (@id, @user, @guild, @points, @level);");
});

client.on("messageCreate", message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  let score;
  if (message.guild) {
    score = client.getScore.get(message.author.id, message.guild.id);
    if (!score) {
      score = { id: `${message.guild.id}-${message.author.id}`, user: message.author.id, guild: message.guild.id, points: 0, level: 1 }
    }
    score.points++;
    const curLevel = Math.floor(0.1 * Math.sqrt(score.points));
    if (score.level < curLevel) {
      score.level++;
      message.reply(`You've leveled up to level **${curLevel}**! Ain't that dandy?`);
    }
    client.setScore.run(score);
  }
  if (message.content.indexOf(config.prefix) !== 0) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === "give") {
    // Limited to guild owner - adjust to your own preference!
    if (!message.author.id === message.guild.ownerId) return message.reply("You're not the boss of me, you can't do that!");
  
    const user = message.mentions.users.first() || client.users.cache.get(args[0]);
    if (!user) return message.reply("You must mention someone or give their ID!");
  
    const pointsToAdd = parseInt(args[1], 10);
    if (!pointsToAdd) return message.reply("You didn't tell me how many points to give...");
  
    // Get their current points.
    let userScore = client.getScore.get(user.id, message.guild.id);
  
    // It's possible to give points to a user we haven't seen, so we need to initiate defaults here too!
    if (!userScore) {
      userScore = { id: `${message.guild.id}-${user.id}`, user: user.id, guild: message.guild.id, points: 0, level: 1 }
    }
    userScore.points += pointsToAdd;
  
    // We also want to update their level (but we won't notify them if it changes)
    let userLevel = Math.floor(0.1 * Math.sqrt(score.points));
    userScore.level = userLevel;
  
    // And we save it!
    client.setScore.run(userScore);
  
    return message.channel.send(`${user.tag} has received ${pointsToAdd} points and now stands at ${userScore.points} points.`);
  }
  
  if (command === "leaderboard") {
    /*const top10 = sql.prepare("SELECT * FROM scores WHERE guild = ? ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 10;").all(message.guild.id);*/
  
      // Now shake it and show it! (as a nice embed, too!)
    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setTitle("Leader board")
      .setDescription("Our top 10 points leaders!")
      .setColor("#ff0000")
      .addFields({ name: '\u200b', value: '\u200b' });
  
    /*for (const data of top10) {
      embed.addFields({ name: client.users.cache.get(data.user).tag, value: `${data.points} points (level ${data.level})` });
    }*/
    return message.channel.send({ embed: embed });

  }
  // Command-specific code here!
});
```

The Idea is that when someone messages in chat, the bot will see that message and randomize the amount of XP given to a member. I dont have a full idea on how this can be done externally, if it can.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand this correctly, you want another JS file to be run inside of your current file. Node JS makes this pretty easy!

```
require('./filename.js')
```

(also, you might want to use external files to store your commands too!)